# Is it possible to sustain an net electric charge density in a moving conductor? (MHD application)

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge, magnetohydrodynamics

The conservation of electric charge, deduced from the divergence of the Maxwell-Ampère equation, takes the form:
$$ \nabla \cdot \textbf{J} = -\frac{\partial \rho_e}{\partial t}.$$

For low frequency application, the quasi-magnetostatic approximation leads us to:
$$\nabla \times \textbf{B} = \mu_0\textbf{J} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \nabla \cdot \textbf{J} = 0.$$

This relationship is typical of highly conductive media in which the phenomenon of electric charge relaxation appears. This can be illustrated by taking the divergence of Ohm's law [$\textbf{J} = \sigma \left(\textbf{E}+\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B}\right)$] associated with the Maxwell-Gauss law:
$$\frac{\partial\rho_e}{\partial t}+\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0}\rho_e+\sigma\nabla\cdot(\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B})=0.$$

If we first assume a static situation where $\textbf{u}= \textbf{0}$, the previous equation
is simplified and the solution is:
$$\rho_e(t) = \rho_e(0)\exp(-t/\tau),$$

where $\tau = \varepsilon_0/\sigma$ is a characteristic charge disappearance time and is about $10^{-18}$ s in
metallic media. The charge density is therefore approximately zero
in stationary conductors after a short transient regime. In the case of a moving
conductor however, and by neglecting the first term of the previous equation from the previous analysis, the charge density is given by:
$$\rho_e = -\varepsilon_0\nabla\cdot(\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B}).$$
It seems therefore possible to maintain a volumetric charge density in a moving conductor.

My questions are the following : If we take a moving conductive fluid and manage to produce a diverging $(\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B})$ field, can we really sustain a net volumetric charge density in the bulk (and not only a surface charge density)? If so, has it been observed experimentally? Is it measurable? If $\textbf{B}$ is oscillating, does it mean that new currents appear?

The all argument is taken from:

[1] P.A. Davidson. Introduction to magnetohydrodynamics, 2nd edition. Cambridge Texts in Applied Mathematics (2017) and

[2] J.A. Shercliff. A textbook of magnetohydrodynamics. Pergamon Press (1965).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the simplest example is a solid conductive disk rotating in external magnetic field, with lines of force perpendicular to the disk. Charge of one sign concentrates on the rim, charge of the opposite sign is distributed in the disk (with uniform spatial density). A disk made of liquid would behave the same - as long as it is conductive and the flow in it is not too mixing (turbulent), the charge separation effect will be present.

So the effect is really due to motion of conductor in external magnetic field ($\mathbf u $ is velocity of the conductor element), whether the conductor is liquid or not does not matter.

In the inertial frame co-moving with a disk element, there is an "induced" electric field due to the magnet $\mathbf E_m'$ that has value $\mathbf E_m' = \mathbf u\times\mathbf B$, this follows from the rules of how fields transform in special relativity. This electric field pushes on the free charge in the conductor; in case of $\mathbf B$ parallel to $\boldsymbol{\omega}$, it pushes positive charge out towards the rim. When the disk is spinned up, or magnetic field is increased from zero, it thus creates a short-lived current that redistributes charge in the disk. Due to this redistribution, additional electric field $\mathbf E_{d}'$ appears in the same frame, which is due to charge in the disk: it is the sum/integral of all the Coulomb fields of the charges in the disk and its rim. Very quickly, an equilibrium charge distribution and its electric field $\mathbf E_{d}'$ is established, where in the disk, $\mathbf E_{d}' = -\mathbf  E_m' = -\mathbf u\times\mathbf B$, so total force is zero (ignoring the centripetal force needed to make the charge go in circles, which is negligible for achievable angular velocities).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your comment led me to the following paper that deepen your answer : Lorrain, P. (1990). Electrostatic charges in v*B fields: The Faraday disk and the rotating sphere. European Journal of Physics. 11. 94.

Comment: @Antoine Oh my, that paper has some bizarre statements and uses the symbol $\mathbf J$ incoherently. From (1) to (5) $\mathbf J$ means conduction current only, without the advection due to rotating charge density. Then in (6) and (8), $\mathbf J$ has to be total current density, including the advection component $\rho \mathbf v$. Then in (9) to (17), he switches back to $\mathbf J$ being conduction current without $\rho \mathbf v$. What a mess. And (14) for the conduction component of current can be derived much more easily in the rotating frame of the disk.

Comment: Thank you I will check other references. Concerning the charge density, if it is indeed present, do you know how is the phenomenon explained in the rotating frame of a conductive disk ?

Comment: @Antoine I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me but in trying to convince a colleague I am told that $\rho_e = -\varepsilon_0\nabla\cdot(\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B})$ can be rearranged as $\nabla\cdot\textbf{E}= -\nabla(\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B})$ and thus that a net electric charge is not necessarily present but that a diverging $\textbf{E}$ could just result from $\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B}$ having a non-zero divergence, a kind of 'induction' in a way. What do you think of this ?

Comment: No, that's not right. Just because we can rewrite the equation without using the symbol $\rho$, this does not mean that non-zero charge density isn't present. It's a very strange argument - "let me hide the symbol behind other symbols, then quantity represented by that symbol is not present in the system". In EM theory, we can always detect net charge density from the electric field function, via its divergence: $\rho_{net} = \epsilon_0  \nabla\cdot\mathbf E$. So non-zero divergence of the electric field function means non-zero net charge density.

Comment: Maybe your colleague meant that just as divergence of net $\mathbf E$ can be caused by non-zero net charge density, maybe it can be independently caused also by diverging $\mathbf u \times \mathbf B$ in conductor. I think that is a logical possibility when constructing possible theories of the world, but it would be a different theory than the standard EM theory. In the latter, charge density obeys the Gauss law $\rho_{net} = \epsilon_0 \nabla\cdot\mathbf E$ and this is true regardless of the detail of whether the electric field is somehow related to magnetic field or not.

Comment: There is a good causal argument for why there has to be spatial charge: when the disk starts rotating with angular velocity antiparallel to $\mathbf B$, magnetic force in the lab frame starts pushing the negative mobile charge out to the rim, and the charge moves in that sense. So on the boundary rim/cylinder surface, surplus negative charge appears, and in the volume of the disk, that negative charge is missing and that's why there is net positive spatial charge density in the disk.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I feel that I have trouble at distinguishing the total current from the conduction current. If the fields transform as $\textbf{E}'=\textbf{E}+\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B}$ with $\textbf{E}'$ being the electric field in the rotating frame, then from $\textbf{J}'=\sigma\textbf{E}'$ we would get $\nabla\cdot\textbf{J}=0$ and thus $\nabla\cdot\textbf{E}'=0$, so in the rotating frame we would have no charges. I can't see where the argument goes wrong. Once again thank you Ján for your time.

Comment: Maybe I can rephrase that : If $\textbf{J}_c$ is the conduction current that verifies $\textbf{J}_c=\sigma[\textbf{E}+\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B}]$ then from $\textbf{J}_c = \textbf{0}$ and $\nabla\cdot\textbf{J}_c = 0$ in both frames and applying it to $\textbf{J}_c'$ results in $\nabla\cdot\textbf{E}' = 0$ and no charges ?

Comment: We can't expect Maxwell's equations to hold in rotating frames. Instead, we can do analysis for any small disk element $p$ in its co-moving inertial frame: primed symbols $\mathbf E'$ etc. refer to quantities in this specific inertial frame, where the element is at rest. Thus $\mathbf E'(\mathbf x') = \mathbf E + \mathbf u_p \times \mathbf B$  depends on position $\mathbf x'$ via $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$, but not via $\mathbf u_p$, which is the same constant for all $\mathbf x'$. Thus $\mathbf E'=0$ is valid only at the position of the disk element $p$, elsewhere this field does not vanish.

Comment: Since $\mathbf E'$ vanishes certainly only at single point, $\nabla' \cdot \mathbf E'$ in the co-moving inertial frame need not vanish.

Comment: Similarly, $\mathbf J'(\mathbf x') = \sigma \mathbf E'(\mathbf x')$ is valid only at single point $\mathbf x'$ which defines the co-moving inertial frame. Changing value of $\mathbf x'$ requires changing the meaning of the prime symbol, it refers to different inertial frame then. So divergence of both sides of this equation in any single inertial frame need not be zero. Divergence of $\mathbf E'$ would be zero only if by $\mathbf E'$ we meant $\mathbf E(\mathbf x') + \mathbf u(\mathbf x')\times \mathbf B(\mathbf x')$, which is not correct in a single inertial frame.

Comment: Correct evaluation of divergence of $\mathbf E'$ in any co-moving inertial frame should be like this: $\nabla'\cdot\mathbf E' = \nabla'\cdot(\mathbf E + \mathbf u_p\times\mathbf B) = \nabla'\cdot\mathbf E + \nabla'\cdot (\mathbf u_p\times\mathbf B) = \nabla'\cdot\mathbf E + \mathbf B\cdot (\nabla'\times\mathbf u_p) - \mathbf u_p \cdot (\nabla' \times \mathbf B)$.

Comment: Since $\mathbf u_p$ does not depend on position in single co-moving inertial frame, in uniform magnetic field the magnetic term does not contribute at all, and we have $\nabla'\cdot\mathbf E' = \nabla'\cdot\mathbf E$.